# List matching in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I have a function that I'm working on in Ocaml. It consists of a function that takes in two string lists and returns a string list. The function operates as follows. It scans each individual string in the first list and if it finds a corresponding match in the second list, it returns that match. If the second list has a duplicate match, the match would return twice. Here are test cases I've written that describe the expected behavior:

```
let test () : bool =
  (in_both [] ["Pearl"; "Steven"]) = []
;; run_test "in_both empty name list 1" test

let test () : bool =
  (in_both ["Pearl"; "Steven"] []) = []
;; run_test "in_both empty name list 2" test

let test () : bool =
  (in_both ["Pearl"; "Amethyst"; "Henry"] ["Pearl"; "Steven"]) = ["Pearl"]
;; run_test "in_both one repeat in both lists" test

let test () : bool =
  (in_both ["Pearl"; "Amethyst"; "Gary"; "Blair"] ["Pearl"; "Amethyst"; "Blair"]) 
  = ["Pearl";"Amethyst";"Blair"]
;; run_test "in_both three different repeats in both lists" test

let test () : bool =
  (in_both ["Garnet"; "Amethyst"; "Pearl"] ["Pearl"; "Pearl"]) 
  = ["Pearl";"Pearl"]
;; run_test "in_both two repeat in second list" test
```

Here is my function implementation:

```
let rec in_both (names1: string list) (names2: string list) : string list =
  begin match (names1, names2) with
  |([],[])-> []
  |([],hd2::tl2)-> []
  |(hd1::tl1,[])-> []
  |(hd1::tl1,hd2::tl2)->if contains_str names2 hd1 = true then hd1::in_both tl1 
  tl2 else in_both tl1 names2
  end
```

All of my tests pass except the last test, where it looks like `"Pearl"` does not print out twice when it should. What could I be doing wrong in my implementation? For reference, here is the function definition for the contains_str function that I called in in_both:

```
let rec contains_str (l: string list) (name: string) : bool =
  begin match l with
  |[]-> false
  |hd::tl-> hd = name || contains_str tl name
  end
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What about `in_both ["Pearl"; "Pearl"] ["Garnet"; "Amethyst"; "Pearl"]`? Or in other words is `in_both a b == in_both b a`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at it is that `contains_str` is too weak to do what you want. You want to know *how many* times the string appears, not just whether it appears or not. You might consider a function that returns a list of the appearances of string `a` in string list `b` (empty if no appearances).

Also, here is another case your current code doesn't seem to handle properly:

```
# in_both ["a"; "b"] ["b"; "a"];;
- : string list = ["a"]
```

It seems to me there's no reason to move to the tail of the second list (`tl2`) just because `hd1` has been found in it. It may be that the head of the second list appears later in the first list.

Comment: I'll have to give the `contains_str` function more thought. As for the small bug, I modified the then statement to read, `then hd1::in_both tl1 (hd2::tl2)` which should be better, however the function still fails the last test